# Server shuts down by itself?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

Two days ago my intel nuc running ubuntu server (18.04) started shutting itself down randomly (after roughly 1h uptime).

I've updated everything and the problem is still there.

In my /var/log/system I can see the following lines, but really no reason for the shutdown. Any ideas of where I can digg?

```
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Availability of block devices...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Deferred execution scheduler...
Apr 30 14:59:56 aaa-1 systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact that it's shutting down _gracefully_ rather than simply freezing/hanging/rebooting is unexpected, but those machines are notorious for having overheating problems, especially passive-cooling (fanless) designs. It could be that a temperature sensor is triggering the shutdown. Installing the `sensord` monitoring daemon from the `lm_sensors` distribution would let you regularly log sensor data so you can keep an eye on the environmentals. One Fedora user also [had a freeze issue](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-30-randomly-freezes/1698/16) which an SSD firmware update fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Intel NUC with CentOS. Sometimes back, I faced the same issue: shutting down after different intervals. I thought the problem was with CentOS but later I found that it was a thermal issue.

I solved it by updating the BIOS and setting Fan Control Mode to "Balanced and Cool" in BIOS -> Advanced -> Colling tab.

Also, I removed all the junk papers that were blocking the flow of air to NUC.

Hope this works for you too.